# Merging PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays:

array1:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [time] => 12:10:23 [date] => 2013-03-24 )
```

array2:

```
Array ( [id] => 2 [time] => 12:10:25 [date] => 2013-03-25 )
```

I would like to merge them so they result in the following (EDITED):

```
Array ( [id] => 1
             => 2
        [time] => 12:10:23
               => 12:10:25
        [date] => 2013-03-24 
               => 2013-03-25 
      )
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make any sense. Keys must be unique.

Comment: I guess there is some issue with the resulting array please check it

Comment: That's probably why I am having difficulty with it.

Comment: Array ( array([id] => 1 [time] => 12:10:23 [date] => 2013-03-24), 
         array([id] => 2 [time] => 12:10:25 [date] => 2013-03-25) ) Do you mean this

Comment: @ChristopherJBLuck : There can not be same key in an array, if it there last one will override all others

Comment: Are you sure you are not supposed to end up with an array, that contains these two arrays? (as opposed to what you've described, which is an array that contains the _elements from_ two arrays.) **EDIT:** as per @joeframbach recent answer ;-)

Comment: I need a single array that has these three keys. Merging them, I hope to have the data from both arrays merged under the same key.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually mean to have the output:

```
Array (
    Array ([id] => 1 [time] => 12:10:23 [date] => 2013-03-24 ),
    Array ([id] => 2 [time] => 12:10:25 [date] => 2013-03-25 )
)
```

Then you want to use the following code:

```
$newArray = array($array1, $array2);
```

To get the element with the most recent date:

```
$most_recent = $newArray[0];
foreach($newArray as $compare)
{
    if($compare['time'] > $most_recent['time'])
    {
        $most_recent = $compare;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I then get the most recent date and time from this array?

Comment: Edited to reflect the comment

Comment: Good stuff - from this how can I get the ID value of the most recent date? I now need the ID value placed into a separate variable?

Comment: It sounds like you have more issues than can be resolved in StackOverflow comments. Distill exactly what you need into a single complete question. I recommend creating a new question that it complete rather than continuing to edit this existing question.